# Triangular fields accents or decorations with css

Tags: html, css

I came across this page of a themed website that has form field labels with triangles on one side:
http://www.openblackbelt.com/app/index.php?action=profile

A triangle technique is a nice accent to break up the monotony of forms without the usual rounded border or some other getting-over-used approach.

The only problem is, I can't seem to actually determine how the triangular accenting is done.  I don't see any use of `:before` or `:after`, and there is only one html element `<label>` involved as far as I can tell.  Can anyone do a breakdown of how to perform this technique on my own?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/rpdZR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing but a small `div` positioned relative containing absolute positioned `div` using `CSS Triangles`. I've made a demo from scratch, you can check this out.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HjmyZ/)

```
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px; 
    border-bottom: 30px solid #f00;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

If you want to save an element, you can use `:after` pseudo(won't work in IE), you can try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HjmyZ/1/)

```
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px; 
    content: " ";
    border-bottom: 30px solid #f00;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

No `span` tag required here.

Explanation: I am just using an absolute position element with a `height` and `width` set to 0 and am using borders around the element, making one a transparent, thus creating that triangle shape. And than I use `right` to position it correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't seem to get the inspect tool to detect/show that an :after existed, for some reason, which confused me but the second technique will certainly work, based on the demo, so thanks!

Comment: @Kzqai You won't get the after element physically in the dom :)

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Ok, must be pretty much the same technique then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They do it by giving it a `border-bottom:24px;` and `border-right:24px;` by positioning the `div` `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

@feitla is on the right path, @Kzqai specific what you asked for is achieved as below:

CSS:

```
.contact-form label {
border-right: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="openbb_username">Enter your email address</label>
```